# timestamp function Pluse 1 hour PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

I am tring to get a set time timestamp for e.g

if I input the follow time 09:00 i want to see the timestamp for today

```
function GetTimestamp($time){
date();
}

return GetTimestamp("09:00")
```

can someone help me please or lead me down the right path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use the [**`strtotime()`**](https://www.php.net/strtotime) function, passing it your time :

```
$ts = strtotime('09:00');
var_dump($ts);
```

And you'll get :

```
int 1300435200
```

Note : if you don't specify the date, `strtotime` will use *today*.

You could also use the [**`DateTime`**][2] class :

```
$dt = new DateTime('09:00');
$ts = $dt->format('U');
var_dump($ts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('09:00');
```